# How to play audio file from amazon s3 bucket into android media player?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-mediaplayer

I am using an android media player to play audio in my app. URL I am using to set data source in media player is from s3 amazon bucket, which is stored in amazon server. That file is come by using FTP protocol.

**Problem:**
If I check the URL that I am using, in-browser then it automatically starts downloading (as it is using FTP). And if I check in my app then it will take too much time to start (for e.g. 7 min of a clip of size 10 MB takes 1 min to play)

I conclude that MediaPlayer first downloads that audio from the URL and then starts playing. So it takes time to Download.

I want the way that it can directly start playing inside the media player instead of downloading first.

URL type: https://demo-podcast.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/media/clips/41e7d280-cde1-4676-95ff-f7026ae6bdde.mp3

Does anyone know anyway? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
Here my code for mediaplayer, I am using it in recyclerview.

```
 private fun attachMusic(data: ClipsResponse.ClipsResponseItem, binding: ItemLayoutCardBinding, mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {

    binding.apply {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(data.audioUrl)
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            setControls(this, mediaPlayer)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle)
            it.release()
        }
    }
}

private fun setControls(binding: ItemLayoutCardBinding, mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    binding.apply {
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.duration)
        mediaPlayer.start()
        playCycle(this, mediaPlayer)
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle)
            playProgressBar.isVisible = false
          )
        }
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress)
                    
                }
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
        })
    }
}

private fun playCycle(binding: ItemLayoutCardBinding, mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    val handler = Handler()
    binding.apply {
        try {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)
          
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                val runnable = Runnable { playCycle(binding, mediaPlayer) }
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100)
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this Pre-Signed url for the file from s3 bucket ?

Comment: Its public URL for now @MaulikDadhaniya

Comment: Can you share your code @Krupa?

Comment: I have edit it, please check @MaulikDadhaniya

Comment: ok let me check then update you

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **mediaPlayer.prepare()** in code and add **mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()**

Comment: It is deprecated in kotlin so I am using ```mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())```

Comment: ```mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()``` is also not working. it just change your main thread into background thread but doing same thing, download first then play